# Matlab: Generating different random numbers in each parfor loop

Tags: matlab, random, parfor, random-seed

I have the following piece of code:

```
nruns=100
nloops=2
zz=zeros(nloops,nruns);

for wLoop=1:nloops
delete(gcp('nocreate'));
parpool(npools);
parfor wRun=1:nruns
zz(wLoop,wRun)=rand
end
end
disp('done')

size(unique(zz))
```

Every time the pool gets closed and reopened, it appears that the seed gets reinitialised to its default value, so that I get far fewer different numbers than the expected nruns*nloops.
This behaviour does not change if I add

```
rng('shuffle','combRecursive')
```

either inside or just before the parfor. 
If I don't close the pool at every iteration there is no problem, however using a different pool on each iteration is necessary for the usage I have in mind. 
How can I get genuinely different random numbers upon each iteration of the parfor loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the existing behaviour is documented here: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/control-random-number-streams.html . (Note this is essentially the same as MATLAB itself - it always starts up with a completely deterministic random number generator state - although the iterations in a `parfor` loop are not actually dispatched deterministically).

To answer your question - you could adapt the approach outlined [in this doc page](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/repeat-random-numbers-in-parfor-loops.html). Here's one way:

```
% Shuffle the state at the client
rng('shuffle');
% Pick an offset
streamOffset = randi(10000);

out = zeros(10);
for idx = 1:10
    parfor jdx = 1:10
        setupRandStream(idx + streamOffset, jdx);
        out(idx, jdx) = rand;
    end
end

% Set up the global random number state to the specific stream
% and substream using combined recursive generator.
function setupRandStream(stream, substream)
s = RandStream.create('mrg32k3a', 'NumStreams', stream, ...
    'StreamIndices', stream);
s.Substream = substream;
RandStream.setGlobalStream(s);
end
```